# Best practice for Mocking a webservice in MVC with Custom Repository (in Agile Methodology)

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc-3, codeigniter, mocking

I am building a web application using MVC architecture. I will need to consume a webservice which is still under development (we are following Agile methodology). The webservice has several methods. Couple of Methods are stable (published & running) and some methods are still under development.

So this means, from the client I need to Mock the new methods (till they are ready) and keep using the old methods (for regression testing).

What are the best practices for Mocking a service at the Method level? Any suggestions or ideas are welcome. Can I use any Mocking framework?

I am going apply this on ASP.Net MVC framework as well as a PHP application built on CodeIgniter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP, but in PHP when I need to interact with a remote service, I mock the entire service, because I need to test my application/library and not the remote service. So my question is: Why do you care about the remote service in tests ?

Comment: The exception handing at different level is also within scope of testing. We cannot do SIT without realtime service integration.

Comment: You can simulate unexpected result received from web service using a mock to. This way you will also reduce running time of the test suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using Dependancy Injection we cannot switch between Mock & Real Service at method level. In other words, we will need to use **eiether** Mock **or** RealTime service.

Referring to the example above by Forty-Two,

I will be switching between Mock or Real implementation of `IServiceWrapper` from `RegisterUnityMapping`.

This is a feasible approach at my development team. While in local dev environment, when I sometime switch to the Mock for running couple of Unit Tests - otherwise, the real implementation is always used. Need less to say, in higher environment - only Real implementation is used.

Som

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to do this.  This is what I do.  It may or may not fall into the "best practice" category.

I write a wrapper with an interface for the web service.

So say our WebService has four methods, `Get()`, `Create()`, `Update()`, `Delete()`.

My  interface is pretty simple

```
public interface IServiceWrapper
{
  object Get();
  object Create(object toCreate);
  object Update(object toUpdate);
  bool Delete(object toDelete);
}
```

Now I can have two implemetations.
One that calls the actual webservice

```
public class ServiceWrapper : IServiceWrapper
{
  public object Get(){//call webservice Get()}
  public object Create(object toCreate){//call webservice Create()}
  public object Update(object toUpdate){//call webservice Update()}
  public bool Delete(object toDelete){//call webservice Delete()}
}
```

And a Fake (or mock) implementation where I mimic the webservice behavior (generally with in memory data)

```
public class FakeServiceWrapper : IServiceWrapper
{
  private void PopulateObjects()
  {
     //mimic your data source here if you are not using moq or some other mocking framework
  }
  public object Get(){//mimic behavior of webservice Get()}
  public object Create(object toCreate){//mimic behavior of webservice Create()}
  public object Update(object toUpdate){//mimic behavior of webservice Update()}
  public bool Delete(object toDelete){//mimic behavior of webservice Delete()}
}
```

Generally I will use either one or the other by injecting an instance into the consuming service or controller.  But you could easily instantiate an instance of each wrapper and 'pick and choose' at the method level if you wanted to.

Comment: we are going to consume the service in the server side. So you are suggesting to inject the Mocks at the Service level. My project structure is laid out as below...

Controller --->Custom (Class Library) --->Service (Class Library)--->Service Proxy

Do you want me to inject Mock at the Custom level, or at the Service level. Is there a way to switch between 'Mock' & 'Service' just by switching the configuration. That will be the ideal solution by us.

Comment: You can implement this in whatever level best suits you.  If I'm using the web service for all of my data access, I'll have this in the DAL, otherwise I might have a separte layer just for web service wrappers, that interfaces with my 'normal' DAL.  It's entirely up to you.  As far as switching between the real service and the fake, you simply inject your consuming class with the appropriate instance.  Pass the fake service into your test class and the real service into your controller, or custom, or wherever you need it.